# How to convert a shapefile polygon to raster in C#

Tags: c#, rasterization, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

Does anybody know a way to convert a polygon (vector) in a shapefile to raster data WITHOUT using ArcGIS Explorer Desktop? Is there a way to do this 'progmatically' in C# (WPF with ArcGIS runtime library)?

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GDAL liblary. Gdal_rasterize can handle it easily. Here is the [link](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am late in the reply but it will help someone in the future. The http://gis-techniques.blogspot.com/2015/09/vector-to-raster-conversion-using-gdal-c.html provides a details description on rasterize layer using C# and Gdal without any ArcGIS dependency.